# Having trouble using backticks to format in unordered lists for answers

Tags: support

Suppose I were to try to format something in an unordered list with backticks like so:

```
<ul>
    <li>Something here</li>
    <li>Something `else` here</li>
</ul>
```

It would then be rendered as

- Something here
- Something `else` here

and so the second bullet does not have

Something `else` here

which is what I wanted to do. Is there a way to have "`else`" appear like so in a list?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This....

```
- Something here  
- Something `else` here
```

renders like this:

- Something here
- Something `else` here

which I think is what you want.

Comment: Yep, that'll work. Accepting this answer once the 15 minutes is up.

Comment: And as for the *why*: though Markdown does support plain HTML (and SE allows for a limited set of such HTML tags), [using HTML *does* break out of the Markdown syntax](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#html): *"Note that Markdown formatting syntax is not processed within block-level HTML tags. E.g., you can’t use Markdown-style `*emphasis*` inside an HTML block."*, @Dennis.

Comment: Good to know. I'll keep that in mind next time I mix markdown and HTML.

Answer (score 4):

While Stack Overflow supports a [limited set of html](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/1777/182513), Markdown is a better option in many cases.  In fact the menu provides quick access to many of the basic features:

[image]

But if you want to do it manually, then:

```
- Something here  
- Something `else` here
```

will render to:

- Something here
- Something `else` here

The [editing help](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help) page of the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) provide a good summary of the formatting options that are available to you.